# spaces in Batch strings

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a random enchanted weapon generator. However, every once in a while the batch file closes when an enchantment with a space is randomly selected.

I've already tried putting the string in quotes, but then when I use a variable to display the string, the string has the quotation marks.
For Example:

```
if %enchantment% == 1 set enchantment="Health Absorbing"
```

But then when I display %enchantment% it shows up with "Health Absorbing" rather than Health Absorbing.

I've also tried putting the variable in quotes as well, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```
if %enchantment% == 30 set "enchantment=Health Absorbing"
```

Here's a smaller version of my code so far:

```
@echo off

:Weapon
set /a weapon=%random% * 3 / 32768 + 1
if %weapon% == 1 set weapon=Battleaxe
if %weapon% == 2 set weapon=Sword
if %weapon% == 3 set weapon=Mace

:Enchant
set /a enchantmenttype=%random% * 2 / 32768 + 1
if %enchantmenttype% ==1 goto Enchant1
if %enchantmenttype% ==2 goto Enchant2

:Enchant1
set /a enchantment=%random% * 3 / 32768 + 1
if %enchantment% == 1 set enchantment=Flaming
if %enchantment% == 2 set enchantment=Holy
if %enchantment% == 3 set enchantment=Frozen
set "EW=%enchantment% %weapon%"
goto EW

:Enchant2
set /a enchantment=%random% * 3 / 32768 + 1
if %enchantment% == 1 set "enchantment=the Fire Spirit"
if %enchantment% == 2 set "enchantment=the Frozen Spirit"
if %enchantment% == 3 set "enchantment=the Phantom Spirit"
set "EW=%weapon% of %enchantment%"
goto EW

:EW
echo %EW%
pause >nul
goto Weapon
```

I want the code to be able to display a random enchantment with a random weapon every time you press a button. However, the code only does this 1-10 times before it unexpectedly shuts down.

Comment: I'd change the random number generation to `set /A weapon=%random% %% 3 + 1` (but that's probably a matter of taste). The code seems to be fine. Since you are comparing numbers, consider to use `if %weapon% equ 1` rather than `if %weapon% == 1`. Anyway, what I don't like is that you are using the same variable names for the random number and for the weapon/enchantment text; perhaps this lets you confuse something in your full program. To debug it, open a Command Prompt window and run the batch file from there by typing its path/name, and temporarily change `@echo off` to `@echo on`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes on both sides of your comparisons. This way, the contents of the variable gets treated as a single item. However, you have to include the quotes on the other side of the `==` because the quotes are included in the comparison.

```
@echo off

:Weapon
set /a weapon=%random% %% 3 + 1
if "%weapon%"=="1" set weapon=Battleaxe
if "%weapon%"=="2" set weapon=Sword
if "%weapon%"=="3" set weapon=Mace

:Enchant
set /a enchantmenttype=%random% %% 2 + 1
if "%enchantmenttype%"=="1" goto Enchant1
if "%enchantmenttype%"=="2" goto Enchant2

:Enchant1
set /a enchantment=%random% %% 3 + 1
if "%enchantment%"=="1" set enchantment=Flaming
if "%enchantment%"=="2" set enchantment=Holy
if "%enchantment%"=="3" set enchantment=Frozen
set "EW=%enchantment% %weapon%"
goto EW

:Enchant2
set /a enchantment=%random% %% 3 + 1
if "%enchantment%"=="1" set "enchantment=the Fire Spirit"
if "%enchantment%"=="2" set "enchantment=the Frozen Spirit"
if "%enchantment%"=="3" set "enchantment=the Phantom Spirit"
set "EW=%weapon% of %enchantment%"
goto EW

:EW
echo %EW%
pause >nul
goto Weapon
```